# Tagging/annotating every frame in the video with the activity performed using OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I have human pose coordinates in a CSV file, for a particular activity. I have written a predict function which detects the activity(sitting, standing, bending) according to these coordinates. I have the activity in the form of a list. I would like to use this activity list as an input to draw() and show that on the frame. I would appreciate any help. 
[image]
I have tried this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_source)
width = int(vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4",-1,20.0,0,(width,height))
df = pd.read_csv(path)
f_no = 0
labels = detectors.check(normalized_data)

while (cap.isOpened()) :
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        if f_no == df.frameCount.values:
            try:
            label = detectors.check(normalized_data)  ## we need the normalix\zed data one list at a time
            except:
                pass     
        cv2.putText(frame,label,(105,105),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,2,(0,0,255))
        cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        else:
            ##increment 
            f_no +=1
```